# select2 on Laravel Livewire does not work

Tags: laravel, jquery-select2, laravel-livewire

I implemente select2 in a select as the official documentation indicates and I can't get it to work in full.

```
<div>
<div wire:ignore>
    <select class="js-example-basic-single" name="state">
        <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
        <option value="WY">Wyoming</option>
    </select>

    <!-- Select2 will insert it's DOM here. -->
</div>
```

```
@push('scripts')
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.js-example-basic-single').select2();
        $('.js-example-basic-single').on('change', function (e) {
            @this.set('foo', e.target.value);
        });
    });
</script>
@endpush
```

if I remove the following script in the view the select2 component renders fine

```
$('.js-example-basic-single').on('change', function (e) {
                @this.set('foo', e.target.value);
            });
```

but of course I lose the desired functionality.

The selct2 add links I use are as follows

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="{{asset('SitioWeb/assets/select2/js/select2.min.js')}}"></script>
```

what am i missing?

Comment: Any errors in console?

Comment: Hello, yes. Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token, the marked line is the following: @this.set('foo', e.target.value);

Comment: Does this help? The `addEventListener("livewire:load"` part : https://github.com/livewire/livewire/issues/883#issuecomment-620181049

Comment: I don't get the same error.

Answer (score 2):

Due to the way select2 works, livewire's wire:model and wire:change may not work with select2. Livewire's wire:model and wire:change work perfectly with the traditional HTML select control. To use select to with livewire's wire:model and wire:change, write a js code to get the selected value from select2, then use `Livewire.emit()` to send the selected value to your component and handle it from there. Example js code is as follows:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#id').select2();
        $('#id').on('change', function(e) { 
            Livewire.emit('listenerReferenceHere', 
            $('#id').select2("val"));
        });
    });
```

Your Livewire component :

```
...
protected $listeners = ['listenerReferenceHere'];

public function listenerReferenceHere($selectedValue)
{ 
    //Do something with the selected2's selected value here
}
```

I hope this helps...

Answer (score 1):

you can use Bootstrap-select

> npm install bootstrap-select

It worked well for me. this my code.

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="permissions">{{ __('role.permissions') }}</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
        <div wire:key="UNIQUE_KEY">
            <div wire:ignore>
                <select id="permissions" wire:model="permissions"
                        data-live-search="true"
                        data-actions-box="true"
                        title="{{__('generic.select')}} {{ __('role.permissions') }}"
                        name="permissions[]" data-width="100%"
                        class="selectpicker permissions" multiple>
                    @foreach($list_permission as $permission)
                        <option value="{{ $permission->id }}"
                                data-subtext="{{ $permission->key }} {{ ' -'. $permission->table_name }}">

                            {{ __('permission.'.$permission->key) }}
                        </option>
                    @endforeach
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
        @error('permissions') <span class="text-danger">{{ $message }}</span> @enderror
    </div>
</div>
```

in script :

```
   ....
   @push('scripts')
        <script>
            Livewire.restart();
            $(function () {
                $('.permissions').selectpicker();
            });
        </script>
    @endpush
</div>
```

in Component

```
public $permissions = [];
public $old_permissions = [];

public function updatedPermissions()
{
    $filter_arrays = array_filter($this->permissions);
    $unique = array_unique($filter_arrays);
    $this->permissions = $unique;
}
```

in update :

```
 if (! empty($this->old_permissions)){
     $updateRole = $this->role->find($this->modelId)->permissions()->detach();
     $updateRole = $this->role->find($this->modelId)->permissions()->sync($validatedData['permissions']);

  }elseif ($this->old_permissions != $this->permissions ){
     $updateRole = $this->role->find($this->modelId)->permissions()->attach($validatedData['permissions']);
   }
```

Comment: works great ... cheers

Answer (score 0):

I tried hard to combine livewire with select2 and finally found the solution that way.

UsersComponent.php

```php
class Users extends Component
{
    public $users = [];

    public function mount()
    {
        $this->users= User::all();
    }

    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.users');
    }
}
```

then

users.blade.php

```php
<div class="col-sm-12 col-xl-3 m-b-30" wire:ignore >
    <div >
        <h4 class="sub-title" >USERS</h4>
        <select class="js-example-basic-single form-control-warning" name="states" >

            @foreach ($users as $user)
                <option value="{{ $user->id }}">{{ $user->name}}</option>
            @endforeach

        </select>
    </div>

</div>
```

index.blade.php

```php
<p>
@livewire(livewire.users)
</p>
```

Comment: I dont think this code will work one submit .

Comment: I don't understand that. how it work on on change